# React Router not getting data from request like path="/products?category=:category"

Tags: reactjs

I am use react-router-dom.
I have this kind of Route:

```
<Route exact path="/products?category=:category" component={Catalog} />
```

But I am not getting :category on catalog page.
Trying to catch data with this code:

```
const params: { category: any } = useParams();
const category = params.category;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`:

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Catalog() {

  const search = useLocation().search;
  const category = new URLSearchParams(search).get('category');

  return (
      <h1>{ category }</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Its getting null for category

Comment: React router doesn't support dynamic value for query parameter. So, the `route` should be defined like: `<Route path="/products" component={Catalog} />`
And then you can pass any query parameter with any value like: `products?category=shirt`
You can then get the value of query parameter from the component by following the above code

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're getting is a URL query. Get it using `useLocation()`

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
const category = query.get("category") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query string gets passed as the second argument to the component, in an object called search.

Router:

```
<Route exact path="/products" component={Catalog} />
```

Component:

```
const Catalog = ({ match, params }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Query Params: {params.search}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! what is search? where its coming from in params?

Comment: @Oleg `<Route>` automatically passes this parameter to the rendering component. Take a look: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props

Comment: 'search' is a built in property of the URL interface, along with 'path', and not just specific to React. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search